# Error:(26, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Error:(26, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+ 
Install Repository and sync project
Show in File
Show in Project Structure dialog

Note- I clicked install repository , but error message was shown: all packages are not available;
Note- I use local gradle distribution of version 3.3 and maven repo uses version 4.1 so it isn't working too

```
build.gradle project

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all 
sub- projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `google()` in both `repositories` from project `build.gradle`

Comment: add 
1. gradel 3.3
2. google() repository

in app level build.gradle
1.     compileSdkVersion 27,   targetSdkVersion 27
2. in dependencies update     implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'